# How to jump by using x64 memory address, stored at x64 location?

Tags: assembly, x86, 64-bit, x86-64

As far as I know 'jmp' by using a 64bit address as operand is impossible but I believe using a x64 memory location is (from [here](http://www.tptp.cc/mirrors/siyobik.info/instruction/JMP.html) JMP r/m64). But how can I write this in hex?

Illustration of what instruction I want hex opcode of:

```
qword memAddress

jmp far qword ptr [memAddress]
```

Comment: Any ideas - the opcode is REX.W + FF /5 JMP m16:64

Comment: You didn't specify processor type but I figure I'd point out that JMP m16:64 is only available on Intel x64 and not available on AMD's x64

Answer (score 2):

`jmp far` doesn't take a qword memory operand, it takes an 80-bit `m16:64` operand to be loaded into CS:RIP.

**I think you want to leave out the `far` and use an indirect near jump that only modifies RIP, not CS.**  You say you want `JMP r/m64`, and that's what this is.

In NASM syntax, `qword` is the default operand-size for indirect jumps:

```
default rel
label:
    jmp [rel label]
```

Assembles + disassembles (`objdump -drwC -MIntel`) to this:

`ff 25 fa ff ff ff       jmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0xfffffffffffffffa]        # 401000 <label>`

---

See also [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code) if you pointer is an assemble-time constant, e.g. for JIT.  (e.g. `mov rax, 0x123456789ab` / `jmp rax` or `call rax` is also an option.)

Comment: (My example code block uses the machine code as a pointer, which is weird.  Normally you'd put the label somewhere else, in front of some static storage for a function pointer.   I think I was just demoing the syntax and how it assembles, not a useful choice of where to load a new RIP from.)

Answer (score 1):

```
jmp far qword ptr [memAddress]
```

For what it is worth. My assembler produces this : 48h,FFh,2Ch,25h,00h,00h,00h,00h