# Why does 64-bit VC++ compiler add nop instruction after function calls?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, 64-bit, disassembly

I've compiled the following using Visual Studio C++ 2008 SP1, `x64` `C++` compiler:

[image]

I'm curious, why did compiler add those `nop` instructions after those `call`s?

PS1. I would understand that the 2nd and 3rd `nop`s would be to align the code on a 4 byte margin, but the 1st `nop` breaks that assumption.

PS2. The C++ code that was compiled had no loops or special optimization stuff in it:

```
CTestDlg::CTestDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CTestDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    m_hIcon = AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_MAINFRAME);

    //This makes no sense. I used it to set a debugger breakpoint
    ::GdiFlush();
    srand(::GetTickCount());
}
```

PS3. **Additional Info:** *First off, thank you everyone for your input.*

Here's additional observations:

1. My first guess was that [incremental linking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/235007/843732) could've had something to do with it. But, the `Release` build settings in the `Visual Studio` for the project have `incremental linking` off.
2. This seems to affect `x64` builds only. The same code built as `x86` (or `Win32`) does not have those `nop`s, even though instructions used are very similar:

[image]

3. I tried to build it with a newer linker, and even though the `x64` code produced by `VS 2013` looks somewhat different, it still adds those `nop`s after some `call`s:

[image]

4. Also `dynamic` vs `static` linking to MFC made no difference on presence of those `nop`s. This one is built with dynamical linking to MFC dlls with `VS 2013`:

[image]

5. Also note that those `nop`s can appear after `near` and `far` `call`s as well, and they have nothing to do with alignment. Here's a part of the code that I got from `IDA` if I step a little bit further on:

[image]

As you see, the `nop` is inserted after a `far` `call` that happens to "align" the next `lea` instruction on the `B` address! That makes no sense if those were added for alignment only.

6. I was originally inclined to believe that since `near` `relative` `call`s (i.e. those that start with `E8`) are [somewhat faster](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) than `far` `call`s (or the ones that start with `FF`,`15` in this case)

[image]

the linker may try to go with `near` `call`s first, and since those are one byte shorter than `far` `call`s, if it succeeds, it may pad the remaining space with `nop`s at the end. But then the example (5) above kinda defeats this hypothesis.

So I still don't have a clear answer to this.

Comment: Was this a debug build?

Comment: @rex: Obviously no.

Comment: To pad for alignment?

Comment: Looks suspiciously like RIP-relative indirect calls that were relaxed to direct calls by the linker – indirect calls are a byte longer on x86, so the linker inserted the nops to make them the same length.

Comment: They might be [inserted to allow for breakpoints](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/fc639fd6-ee29-4ae8-9f93-e03caed9cad4/jump-to-local-for-which-a-problem-is-created?forum=vstscode), but I'm not sure what they're doing in a release build.

Comment: Do you still get NOPs for a simple program with a single function call?

Comment: I suspect @Fanael is correct. Getting rid of that NOP would mean shifting all the code. But shifting all the code would change a lot of addresses. Seems like a chicken-egg problem that's being solved with NOPs.

Comment: Of course, why use nops for this purpose is beyond me – address override prefixes incur no overhead for direct calls on modern CPUs and unlike nops, they don't count as a separate instruction in the decoders.

Comment: @Mysticial Weird how this isn't necessary with how ELF does (dynamic) linking.

Comment: @fuz With ELF function calls to functions in shared libraries are always made through a stub function. On Windows function calls to functions in DLLs are often made directly using an indirect call instruction. The `call cs:LoadIconW` instruction in the disassembly above is an example of this. The location the disassembler has called `LoadIconW` contains a pointer to the actual `LoadIconW` function.

Comment: @Mysticial: The other option would be to pad the `call` instruction with a prefix, but I'm not sure that's guaranteed to be future-proof.  Some future ISA extension might use `rep call` to mean something special.  I tested, and `call` works on Skylake when preceded by`rep`, or `0x40` (REX.W=0), or `0x48` (REX.W=1).  I'd guess that a REX prefix is more future-proof.  A linker would need to check that there wasn't already a REX prefix, though (e.g. from hand-written code with padding), and that's impossible because you can't unambiguously step backwards in x86.  Multiple REP prefixes would be ok

Comment: The linker does have to know it's a `call` or `jmp` instruction, right?  The opcode has to change from indirect to rel32.  (Hmm, prefixes on `jcc` instructions have special meaning as branch-prediction hints on P4.  But `jcc` can't be indirect anyway, so could only appear for conditional tailcalls that were already using a direct jump.)

Comment: Oh actually, I think `REX` has to be the last prefix if it appears, so checking the byte before the `call` opcode can give false positives (previous instruction ended with `0x4?`), but not false negatives.

Comment: Anyone care to submit an answer? @Fanael, perhaps?

Comment: @PeterCordes "The other option would be to pad the call instruction with a prefix" like an address override prefix, which is free for `call` on pretty much everything and highly unlikely to ever change the meaning of `call`? That's what GNU ld is using.

Comment: @TriskalJM No, I'm not sure what's actually going on here, I'm just speculating, so I don't want to answer.

Comment: Can you show the disassembly of the produced object file and binary side by side? As in before and after linking.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow: Sorry. I'm not really good with object files. I updated my original post with additional details though.

Comment: @c00000fd they're all near calls, far calls are never used on most modern operating systems, because segmentation is dead (to be fair, call gates have some advantages over `syscall` and `sysenter`, but no OS I'm aware of uses them). The difference is direct vs indirect.

Comment: If the `nop`s are still there even with dynamic linking, the linker relaxation idea's gotta be wrong then.

Comment: I think Fanael is correct. The original call is an indirect call and its op-code is one byte longer than direct call. When the packer changed the indirect call to direct call, one nop was padded. Here is a similar question, https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8030/purpose-of-nop-immediately-after-call-instruction

Comment: @Houcheng: There's no "packer" involved in producing that code. It was just compiled by VS2008 compiler.

Comment: Just want to point out that I ended up on this question because of a PDF about static variables initialization in which the author prescribes calling functions (at least in some cases) with a pair of `call/nop`:
« add the necessary call/nop to
those functions within the “.init” section »
(https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~gbournou/CSE131/GlobalAndStaticVars.pdf)
But them doesn't explain why.
Makes the answers here not very satisfying to me.

Answer (score 5):

This is purely a guess, but it might be some kind of a SEH optimization. I say *optimization* because SEH seems to work fine without the NOPs too. NOP might help speed up unwinding.

In the following example ([live demo with VC2017](https://godbolt.org/g/Q53Jqn)), there is a `NOP` inserted after a call to `basic_string::assign` in `test1` but not in `test2` (identical but declared as non-throwing<sup>1</sup>).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int test1() {
  std::string s = "a";  // NOP insterted here
  s += getchar();
  return (int)s.length();
}

int test2() throw() {
  std::string s = "a";
  s += getchar();
  return (int)s.length();
}

int main()
{
  return test1() + test2();
}
```

Assembly:

```
test1:
    . . .
    call     std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign
    npad     1         ; nop
    call     getchar
    . . .
test2:
    . . .
    call     std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >::assign
    call     getchar
```

Note that MSVS compiles by default with the `/EHsc` flag (synchronous exception handling). Without that flag the `NOP`s disappear, and with `/EHa` (synchronous *and* asynchronous exception handling), `throw()` no longer makes a difference because SEH is always on.

---

<sup>1</sup> For some reason only `throw()` seems to reduce the code size, using `noexcept` makes the generated code even bigger and summons even more `NOP`s. MSVC...

Answer (score 3):

This is special filler to let exception handler/unwinding function to detect correctly whether it's prologue/epilogue/body of the function.

Answer (score -3):

This is due to a calling convention in x64 which requires the stack to be 16 bytes aligned before any call instruction. This is not (to my knwoledge) a hardware requirement but a software one. This provides a way to be sure that when entering a function (that is, after a call instruction), the value of the stack pointer is always 8 modulo 16. Thus permitting simple data alignement and storage/reads from aligned location in stack.

Comment: Although your statement is correct, it has nothing to do with my original question.

Comment: You asked why the nop's are added to the assembly, and that is the reason why. How does that not answer your question ?

Comment: I asked why `nop`s are added after a `call` instruction and not the function itself. What you mentioned applies to the body (or code) of the functions, and not the `call` instruction.

Comment: NOP can pad code to align `RIP` (but it's not in this case; look at the code addresses in the dump).  The calling convention requires `RSP` to be aligned.  NOP doesn't modify `RSP`.