# Why do compilers duplicate some instructions?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang

Sometimes compilers generate code with weird instruction duplications that can safely be removed. Consider the following piece of code:

```
int gcd(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  return x == 0 ? y : gcd(y % x, x);
}
```

Here is the assembly code (generated [by clang 5.0](https://godbolt.org/g/uLqQNv) with optimizations enabled):

```
gcd(unsigned int, unsigned int): # @gcd(unsigned int, unsigned int)
  mov eax, esi
  mov edx, edi
  test edx, edx
  je .LBB0_1
.LBB0_2: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  mov ecx, edx
  xor edx, edx
  div ecx
  test edx, edx
  mov eax, ecx
  jne .LBB0_2
  mov eax, ecx
  ret
.LBB0_1:
  ret
```

In the following snippet:

```
  mov eax, ecx
  jne .LBB0_2
  mov eax, ecx
```

If the jump doesn't happen, `eax` is reassigned for no obvious reason.

The other example is two ret's at the end of the function: one would perfectly work as well.

Is the compiler simply not intelligent enough or there's a reason to not remove the duplications?

Comment: `clang`, `c` or `c++`?

Comment: I've updated the post with a link to the Compiler Explorer.

Comment: Interesting that gcc doesn't do that: https://godbolt.org/g/MxTiaY.

Comment: May be somehow related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854497/why-does-64-bit-vc-compiler-add-nop-instruction-after-function-calls

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with branch prediction.

Comment: Ot it might just be a missing optimization.

Comment: @lisyarus gcc *does* do it

Comment: @Justin Indeed, there are at least several seemingly duplicate `mov eax, edi`. Thank you, I didn't notice it at first.

Comment: @Barmar branch prediction happens runtime not compile time.

Comment: Sometimes an optimizer will try to influence how the CPU will predict the branch.

Comment: How would adding a `mov` instruction affect the branch predictor?

Comment: Which optimizations enabled?

Comment: The example is -O2 although -O3 does not change the result.

Comment: @Fredrik I think you missing the point, barmar want to say that maybe clang produce this output to increase CPU branch prediction. And barmar was talking about runtime...

Comment: I remember reading either in the gcc internal spec or in the source code that optimization can not happen over edges. All the duplication is happening over edges.

Comment: Please feel free to report this missed optimization to both gcc and llvm. The 2 'mov' are in different basic blocks, which makes the optimization a bit harder, but still desirable.

Comment: Is this about how CLang compiles or compilation in general?

Answer (score 42):

Compilers can perform optimisations that are not obvious to people and removing instructions does not always make things faster.

A small amount of searching shows that various AMD processors have branch prediction problems when a RET is immediately after a conditional branch. By filling that slot with what is essentially a no-op, the performance problem is avoided.

Update:

Example reference, section 6.2 of the "Software Optimization Guide for AMD64 Processors" (see http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/25112.PDF) says:

Specifically, avoid the following two situations:

- Any kind of branch (either conditional or unconditional) that has the single-byte near-return RET instruction as its target. See “Examples.”
- A conditional branch that occurs in the code directly before the single-byte near-return RET instruction.

It also goes into detail on why jump targets should have alignment which is also likely to explain the duplicate RETs at the end of the function.

Comment: @Cornstalks [this](http://mikedimmick.blogspot.com.br/2008/03/what-heck-does-ret-mean.html) my be one.

Comment: @Cornstalks Updated with details.

Comment: Do you have evidence that the compilers are indeed doing it on purpose for this reason? If they want a NOP before the RET, this MOV is far from the simplest they could have gone for. If this only affects AMD cpus, -mtune=intel or similar should remove it, but it doesn't.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Is your question whether I have evidence that optimisation tools are optimising on purpose rather than by accident?  No. It could just be a bug that makes code go faster. Do you have evidence that the generated code is slower on Intel CPUs without the instruction removed?

Comment: I have evidence that the code is longer and still generated at -Os --> bug.

Comment: Is there no *real* NO-OP instruction? Why use an instruction that's only "essentially" a NO-OP?

Comment: Looking at the assembly, my first instinct was that this `mov` following the `jne` is some sort of a [**delay slot**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_slot). That would explain why the compiler generates it even for non-AMD targets.

Comment: @Barmar not really really real, there's just one "essentially a noop" instruction that happens to have the mnemonic `NOP` (it's `XCHG AX, AX`)

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Yes, I agree -- I thought about that, then found the AMD harder requirement. The real point is that scheduling on modern CPUs is not just about short code. There is all kinds of pipeline maintenance required.

Answer (score 5):

Any compiler will have a bunch of transformations for register renaming, unrolling, hoisting, and so on. Combining their outputs can lead to suboptimal cases such as what you have shown. Marc Glisse offers good advice: it's worth a bug report. You are describing an opportunity for a peephole optimizer to discard instructions that either

- don't affect the state of registers & memory at all, or
- don't affect state that matters for a function's post-conditions, won't matter for its public API.

Sounds like an opportunity for [symbolic execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_execution) techniques. If the constraint solver finds no branch points for a given MOV, perhaps it is really a NOP.