# Why does MSVC generate nop instructions for atomic loads on x64?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, atomic, no-op

If you compile code such as

```
#include <atomic>

int load(std::atomic<int> *p) {
    return p->load(std::memory_order_acquire) + p->load(std::memory_order_acquire);
}
```

[you see](https://godbolt.org/z/drGn9f9Wv) that [MSVC generates NOP padding after each memory load](https://twitter.com/Myriachan/status/1455647162348437508):

```
int load(std::atomic<int> *) PROC
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rcx]
        npad    1
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rcx]
        npad    1
        add     eax, edx
        ret     0
```

Why is this? Is there any way to avoid it without relaxing the memory order (which would affect the correctness of the code)?

Comment: Related, maybe answers this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44854497/why-does-64-bit-vc-compiler-add-nop-instruction-after-function-calls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`p->load()` may eventually use the `_ReadWriteBarrier` compiler intrinsic.

According to this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/-readwritebarrier-intrinsic-emits-unnecessary-code/1538997

> the nops get inserted because of the flag /volatileMetadata which is now [on by default](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-backend-updates-in-visual-studio-2019-version-16-10-preview-2/). You can return to the old behavior by adding /volatileMetadata-, but doing so will result in worse performance if your code is ever [run emulated](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/arm64ec-support-in-visual-studio/). It’ll still be emulated correctly, but the emulator will have to pessimistically assume every load/store needs a barrier.

And compiling with `/volatileMetadata-` does indeed remove the `npad`.

Comment: So there can be metadata that means a 1-byte `nop` after a memory access should be treated as some kind of memory barrier when binary-translating to a weakly-ordered ISA?  `_ReadWriteBarrier` only blocks compile-time reordering, but on x86(-64), that after a load is sufficient for an acquire operation, so I guess a translator could recognize that as an acquire load (aarch64 `ldar`)?  It would need a way to signal a full `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)` 2-way barrier (not a 1-way ordered *operation*), so maybe *every* 1-byte NOP is treated as a fence?

Comment: Anyway, yeah that explains that the NOP has some kind of meaning.  Maybe they went with in-band NOPs to be able to support x86-64 JIT engines being aware of this ARM64ec thing?  Otherwise pure metadata with the addresses of atomic operations and barriers could have avoided wasting front-end bandwidth and uop-cache footprint when running on actual x86-64, at a cost in binary size.  But would also give room for more specific info about what kind of memory-order is required.

Comment: @PeterCordes I asked this in MSVC STL Discord, someone (not from MS) [assumed](https://discord.com/channels/737189251069771789/737734473751330856/1060227069625254008) that there's no out-of-band metadata, to save space, possibly ending up with spurious barriers for true NOPs inserted for alignment. This assumptions aligns with my experiments which show no signs of extra metadata.