# What does the "MODULE_INFO(retpoline, "Y")" macro?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I see in some driver source code the line:

MODULE_INFO(retpoline, "Y")

What is does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This macro defines key-value pairs that are stored in the compiled module files. You can use the [`modinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/modinfo.8.html) command to display them. For example, when you compile this module, `modinfo my_module.ko` will include a line

```
retpoline:      Y
```

You can find the [definition](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/include/linux/module.h#L161) of the macro and its documentation (such as it is) by searching on [an LXR interface](https://elixir.bootlin.com/). It works by [defining a symbol in the `.modinfo` section](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h#L23) of the object file.

This mechanism is used for various metadata used by the module loaded in the kernel and by userland tools such as `modprobe`. Standard metadata include [aliases](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/ident/MODULE_ALIAS), [license](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/ident/MODULE_LICENSE), [version](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.2/ident/MODULE_VERSION), etc.

The `retpoline` tag indicates that the module is built with [support for a mitigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089426/what-is-a-retpoline-and-how-does-it-work) against [Spectre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_(security_vulnerability)). I don't know why driver source code would declare this explicitly: as far as I understand, this should automatically be inserted (via a header) when compiling with retpoline support: this is a compiler feature, not a property of the source code.