# what C code will use "JMP EDI" or "PUSH EDI RET"?

Tags: assembly, x86, virtual-machine

Is there any difference between

```
JMP EDI
```

and

```
PUSH EDI
RET
```

what kind of c code will be disassembled this way? 
a dynamically resolved function pointer, then being called?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not really – the effect of these two is the same except that `push edi; ret` overwrites a word on the stack.  No sane C compiler would generate code like this though; it just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a ROP gadget, `volatile int tmp = 0xffe7ffe4` will compile to a `mov` whose immediate contains the machine code bytes for both JMP EDI and JMP ESP.  But of course when executed normally, it's just `mov dword [esp], 0xffe7ffe4` or whatever that the compiler emitted.  Any other use of that `0xffe7` constant may compile to machine code that includes it as an immediate.

**Compilers will never emit push / ret**.  It breaks the return-address predictor stack leading to mispredicts in later returns up the callstack.  Even a [retpoline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48089426/what-is-a-retpoline-and-how-does-it-work) normally only uses call/modify stack/ret.  (GCC will emit retpolines automatically with [`-mindirect-branch=thunk`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/186165/compiling-with-gcc-retpoline-flags)).  You could of course get that 3-byte sequence as an immediate, though.

---

`jmp edi` could possibly come up as a normal part of compiler output (not just embedded as part of another instruction).  But it's unlikely.  In 32-bit calling conventions, `edi` is call-preserved so you won't find `jmp edi` implementing a tailcall; registers have to restored before a return or tailcall.  If you get GCC to keep a function pointer in a register, it will tailcall with `mov eax, edi` / `pop edi` / `jmp eax` to restore its callers value before tailcalling.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/CdJiTT)).

A `call edi` is not that hard to come by with local function pointers, if you use enough other locals that the compiler's register allocator chooses EDI.  But not `jmp`.

In x86-64 System V, RDI is an arg-passing register and call-clobbered, but of course pointers are 64-bit so you'll always get `jmp rdi`.  In the ILP32 variant (the x32 ABI), the calling convention still apparently requires pointer args to be zero-extended to 64-bit because [GCC `-mx32` still emits `jmp rdi`](https://godbolt.org/z/x47Ucz), not `jmp edi`.  (Clang truncates to 32-bit with `mov eax,edi` / `jmp rax`).  Disabling optimization is no use; compilers will then just store to the stack and reload into EAX.

## Working example for gcc9.2

One sure bet is a [GNU C computed-goto to the address of a local label](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:9,endLineNumber:25,positionColumn:9,positionLineNumber:25,selectionStartColumn:9,selectionStartLineNumber:25,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:25),source:'void+ext()%3B%0A%0Atypedef+void+(*fp_type)(void)%3B%0Afp_type+global_fp+%3D+ext%3B++//+global%3B+could+be+modified+by+calls%0A%23if+0%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++void+(*fp)(void)+%3D+global_fp%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A++++ext()%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+bar(int+*p,+fp_type+fp)+%7B%0A++++%2B%2B*p%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A++++ext()%3B%0A++++%2B%2B*p%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0Avoid+use_fp(fp_type+fp)+%7B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+use_local_label(int+*p)%0A%7B%0A++++void+*volatile+target_launder+%3D+%26%26label1%3B%0A++++void+*target+%3D+target_launder%3B+++++++//+defeat+constant-propagation%0A%0A++++label1:%0A++++ext()%3B++//+non-inline+function+call+forces+using+call-preserved+registers%0A++++if+(*%2B%2Bp+%3D%3D+0)+target+%3D+%26%26label2%3B%0A++++goto+*target%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%0A++++label2:%0A++++return+1%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.29965293553238,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O2+-m32+-fcall-used-esi',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:49.700347064467636,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
// function arg and target both need call-preserved registers to survive across ext()
int use_local_label(int *p)
{
    void *volatile target_launder = &&label1;
    void *target = target_launder;       // defeat constant-propagation

 label1:
    ext();  // non-inline function call forces using call-preserved registers
    if (++*p == 0) target = &&label2;
    goto *target;

    return 0;

 label2:
    return 1;
}
```

[**Godbolt gcc9.2** `-O2 -m32 -fcall-used-esi`](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:11,endLineNumber:32,positionColumn:11,positionLineNumber:32,selectionStartColumn:11,selectionStartLineNumber:32,startColumn:11,startLineNumber:32),source:'void+ext()%3B%0A%0Atypedef+void+(*fp_type)(void)%3B%0Afp_type+global_fp+%3D+ext%3B++//+global%3B+could+be+modified+by+calls%0A%23if+0%0Avoid+foo()+%7B%0A++++void+(*fp)(void)+%3D+global_fp%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A++++ext()%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+bar(int+*p,+fp_type+fp)+%7B%0A++++%2B%2B*p%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A++++ext()%3B%0A++++%2B%2B*p%3B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif%0Avoid+use_fp(fp_type+fp)+%7B%0A++++fp()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+use_local_label(int+*p)%0A%7B%0A++++void+*volatile+target_launder+%3D+%26%26label1%3B%0A++++void+*target+%3D+target_launder%3B+++++++//+defeat+constant-propagation%0A%0A+label1:%0A++++ext()%3B++//+non-inline+function+call+forces+using+call-preserved+registers%0A++++if+(%2B%2B*p+%3D%3D+0)+target+%3D+%26%26label2%3B%0A++++goto+*target%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%0A+label2:%0A++++return+1%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50.29965293553238,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O2+-m32+-fcall-used-esi',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:49.700347064467636,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)  (Instead of using a 3rd more local var, I just told the compiler that ESI is call-clobbered to stop it from picking that before EDI.  `p` and `target` end up in EBX and EDI, respectively.)

```
use_local_label:
        push    edi                                # save call-preserved regs
        push    ebx
        sub     esp, 20
        mov     DWORD PTR [esp+12], OFFSET FLAT:.L4   # volatile init
        mov     ebx, DWORD PTR [esp+32]               # p = function arg
        mov     edi, DWORD PTR [esp+12]               # target = volatile reload
.L4:
        call    ext
        add     DWORD PTR [ebx], 1
        je      .L5                # if = conditional jump over the goto
        jmp     edi                # goto *target, normally to .L4
.L5:
        add     esp, 20
        mov     eax, 1
        pop     ebx
        pop     edi
        ret
```