# Absolute addressing using PC-relative addressing in a relocatable program. What would the modification record be like?

Tags: assembly, linker, relocation

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from section 2.2 of *System Software: An Introduction to Systems Programming (For VTU), 3/e* by Leland L. Beck.

> There is an assembler for a machine that has only program-counter
>   relative addressing. If we are to assemble an instruction whose
>   operands is an absolute address in memory - for example LDA 100, to
>   load register A from address (hexadecimal) 100 in memory. How might
>   such an instruction be assembled in a relocatable program?
>
> What relocation operations would be required?

I'm a bit confused about how absolute addressing can be done using PC-relative addressing. I believe the assembler needs to produce a command for the loader, instructing it to store the beginning address of the program (say, `BEGIN`) and jump to the address `100` when it encounters `LDA 100` by reducing `PC` by `PC - 100`, thereby jumping to the absolute address `100` in memory. However, I'm not sure how the modification record would look like.

Could someone please provide some clarification on this?

Comment: PC-relative addressing gives you Position Independent Code, assuming code and data are loaded at the same relative distance no matter where. If this is not the case  (which is rare) the assembler will emit an R_PC_REL relocation (or similar) that will patch the instruction adding the delta in the relative distances (instead of the delta in the loading addresses for an absolute relocation). the assembler can compute the distance for the PC relative instructions when assembling.

Comment: this is a poorly written question, I wish you had a better textbook/school.  If the rule is it ONLY has pc relative addressing then there is no relocation possible because you can only do pc relative addressing.  you cant do math on the program counter and have that result in some other register do the addressing because the machine has only pc-relative addressing.  the answer is trivial  LDA 100 the instruction set does not support anything but pc-relative so the assembler leaves a hole. the linker fills in the offset.

Comment: So, you would load an immediate 100 into an index register and dereference that index register to access absolute address 100.  No relocation required.

Comment: Even if you have absolute addressing: There is no relocation required, since the exact value is already there at assembly time.  Only if you use a label, instead of constant, would the linker need to apply relocation to resolve the symbol's absolute address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'd want a relocation record that gives the absolute address, leaving it up to the dynamic linker / runtime-fixup-applier to calculate the right relative displacement to reach that absolute address from the location where this relocation applies.

It might not be *that* simple.  e.g. x86-64 RIP-relative addressing is relative to the end of the *instruction*, but for example `mov [RIP+rel32], imm32` is encoded with the immediate after the rel32 part of the addressing mode.  But if there's no immediate, it's usually at the end of the instruction.  So the point the addressing mode is relative to might not be a fixed position wrt. the postion you have to apply it.

But we can leave that up to the assembler, and let it add some offset to account for that different in base so relocation will wind up targeting the right absolute address.

This keeps the relocation record compact, the same size as a "normal" one: just a location where to apply it, a type, and a 32-bit absolute address or whatever width the machine uses.  (You could even just encode the absolute address into the spot where the PC-relative offset goes, if that's always wide enough.)

Or the right relative offset to reach the desired absolute address relative to some base, e.g. 0.  That's what GNU/Linux ELF `.o` files use, and so do PIE executables.  That also solves the problem of biasing the relocation to account for any variable distance between where it's stored and where it's relative to.

So for example to relocate the whole image from `0` to `0x10000`, you just subtract `0x10000` from every absolute-target relative relocation.

---

BTW, you can do this in practice for i386 relative call instructions on GNU / Linux with GAS.  Near calls on x86 always use a `call rel32` encoding, but good assemblers on platforms that support the necessary relocations let you write an absolute target and feed the linker the right relocations for you.  ([Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code))

```
# foo.s
.globl _start
_start:
nop                 # some padding so the base of the call address doesn't start at 0
nop
call 0x123456       # relative call to that absolute address
```

Build with `gcc -m32 -c foo.s`, disassemble with `objdump -drwC -Mintel`

```
foo.o:     file format elf32-i386

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   90                      nop
   1:   90                      nop
   2:   e8 52 34 12 00          call   123459 <_start+0x123459> 3: R_386_PC32   *ABS*
```

`readelf -a foo.o` shows the relocations section as follows:

```
Relocation section '.rel.text' at offset 0x94 contains 1 entry:
 Offset     Info    Type            Sym.Value  Sym. Name
00000003  00000002 R_386_PC32
```

The target address isn't part of this relocation record; it's encoded into the existing machine code.  This works for i386 but maybe not always for x86-64.  Building without `-m32` gives us:

```
Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0xb0 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000003  000000000002 R_X86_64_PC32                        123452
```

Either way, note that "offset" is where to apply it (2 NOP bytes plus the opcode byte of "call" means the rel32 starts `3` bytes into the section, starting from a base of 0.)  The `0x123452` in the x86-64 relocation is the real target ...6 minus the length of the rel32 (4 bytes).

The "name + addend" column header makes sense for relocations you'd get from targeting a symbol name with an offset.  e.g. `mov eax, [global_array + 12]` needs to load from 12 bytes past wherever the linker puts the start of `global_array`.

Also note that we're looking at the un-linked `.o` file, not a linked executable.  x86-64 ELF shared objects don't allow runtime fixups for 32-bit absolute targets; the whole object might be randomly located more than +-2GiB away.  (That's why I used `-m32`).

It seems that 32-bit PIE executables don't properly support this either.  Probably because the position-independent is right in the name. :P   Building with `gcc -m32 -pie -nostdlib foo.s` gave us an encoding of `e8 4f 24 12 00` which works for an image base of `0x1000`.  (Even from within GDB after setting a breakpoint and starting the PIE executable to let relocations be applied.)

But if we build with `gcc -m32 -shared -nostdlib foo.s` to make a shared library, text relocations are still allowed:

```
$ gcc -m32 -shared -nostdlib foo.s && objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out

a.out:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

00001000 <_start>:
    1000:       90                      nop
    1001:       90                      nop
    1002:       e8 4f 24 12 00          call   123456 <_DYNAMIC+0x1204ae>
```

Note that disassembly used the relocation info to compute a correct final call target.

But I think that's actually broken because readelf output doesn't show any relocations.  Executing it still fails (to even jump to the right address); we get `0xf7ffc002 <+2>:     e8 4f 24 12 00  call   0xf811e456`

**Anyway, failures of runtime relocation on GNU/Linux are just because I'm abusing text relocations, I think.  The relocation records for `.o` object files do totally work.**